# WCF Named Pipes Endpoint not found

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

In a simple way, we need to do outproc communications through WCF named pipes. In the dev harness the applications both client and service components are instantiated through IOC in the same executable.

Service host:

```
/// <summary>
/// Default constructor
/// </summary>
public OpaRuntimeServiceHost(string serviceName, string hostAddress)
{
    _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(OpaRuntimeService), new Uri[] {
        new Uri(string.Format("net.pipe://{0}/opa/{1}", hostAddress, serviceName))
    });
    _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IOpaRuntimeService), new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None), serviceName);
    _serviceHost.Open();
}
```

Client:

```
/// <summary>
/// Default constructor
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hostAddress"></param>
/// <param name="serviceName"></param>
public OpaRuntimeServiceClient(string serviceName, string hostAddress)
    : base(new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IOpaRuntimeService)),
    new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None), new EndpointAddress(string.Format("net.pipe://{0}/opa/{1}", hostAddress, serviceName))))
{

}
```

Both of which are constructed successfully but when the client calls the service it generates this error:

> There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/opa/runtime that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Unfortunately there's no inner exception. As per other questions I made sure the Net.Pipe Listener service is running. Visual Studio is running with elevated priviledges.

Environments are VS2015 on Windows 10 or VS2012 on Windows 7.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out. Service name was used twice in the service host setup therefore make something like net.pipe://localhost/opa/runtime/runtime when it should have contained this: net.pipe://localhost/opa/runtime. Thanks for the rubber duckie.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the call to AddServiceEndpoint needs the address of the endpoint (according to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585836(v=vs.110).aspx)). In your example code, it looks like you are only passing the serviceName.

I dug up some example code that is doing something similar. However, in my example, I am deriving from ServiceHost:

```
public class CustomServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    public CustomServiceHost() : base(
        new CustomService(),
        new[] { new Uri(string.Format("net.pipe://localhost/{0}", typeof(ICustomService).FullName)) })
    {

    }

    protected override void ApplyConfiguration()
    {
        base.ApplyConfiguration();

        foreach (var baseAddress in BaseAddresses)
        {
            AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICustomService), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), baseAddress);
        }
    }
}
```